# download emacs binary for linux?

Tags: linux, emacs, ubuntu, binary, installation

I am trying to install emacs in offline computer.

but every time I try to build from the source and install it, it doesn't make it.

too complicated.

(terminal ./configure => error try with --without-makeinfo, 
after a while, error try with --without-x, 
after a while, error can't find emacs version...(and I also want to use X version))

so I want to download emacs binary file but I can't find for linux one.

where can I download pre-build binary emacs 23.3(lastest) for ubuntu?

I can download emacs 23.3 binary file for windows but not for ubuntu.

Comment: I suggest downloading a DVD Image and use that to install the emacs that fits your Ubuntu. If you do need to compile your own emacs, you should post the last 4-5 lines so we can see what the error is. (Maybe ask the question over at "Ask Ubuntu"?)

Comment: `apt-get install emacs` is definitely easiest way to install a binary, but it might not be 23.3. Do you absolutely need that version? The latest thing in Ubuntu might be 23.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the deb file directly from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/emacs-snapshot/emacs-snapshot_20090909-1_amd64.deb and then try to install it using `dpkg -i` but there will probably be dependencies which you might miss. I'd suggest you try an `apt-get install emacs-snapshot` on your target machine. It will tell you all the packages it needs to fetch (along with URLs). Fetch all of them from a machine connected to the net and then `dpkg -i` those packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Ubuntu Emacs PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-elisp/+archive/ppa).

Answer (score 0):

type in terminal

```
apt-get update
apt-get install emacs
```

for compile, are you download last version ? http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/

you can download deb file here

http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/emacs23/

Comment: @kim taeyun http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper-backports/powerpc/emacs-snapshot-gtk/download